Can KVM virtual machines share all CPU cores or are they limited by physical core count?
I am a bit of a novice when it comes to KVM and I have a question that I am hoping can be answered rather simply.
If I have a server with 6 cores and set up virtual machines with KVM, are the vCPU's that I can allocate to a VM limited to 6? Or can all VM's share all 6 cores?

The term for this is "over-committing": allocating more resources in total to various things when you can only guarantee one (or a few) of them can claim all of its allocated resources at any given time.

Related (not a dupe): When making a VM, why would I want to not pass it all my cpu cores?

Yes, you can do that. Note that virtual machine execution time needs to get scheduled by the hypervising operating system, so there's no magic increase of compute power that way.
